# Difficulties implementing sorted Doubly Linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I'm taking a class in c++ and one of our assignments is to make an ADT for a linked list and do the implementations. 
I've done well so far. But now I'm supposed to add the elements in order. 
The code below is my ADD-function and what i've accomplished with this code is to sort them GIVEN that there are only 2 elements in the list. (I'm working with the problem from the basics, and refine my code after).
The while-loop on line 11 is my attempt to iterate (and int t are for debugging)

The problem i have is that my program crash without error (cmd stops working) if i try to add a number greater than 5. 
The strange thing here is that if i remove my while-loop, it works. I can't find out whats wrong. So i hope for a little help

Main.cpp:

```
int main() {


   SortedDoublyLinkedList<int> *list = new SortedDoublyLinkedList<int>(5, nullptr, nullptr);
   int counter = 0;
   while (counter < 2) {
       int add;
       cout << "Enter number: ";
       cin >> add;
       list->add(add);

       counter++;
       cout << counter << endl;
   }


    cout << list->removeLast()->getData()<< endl;

    cout << list->removeLast()->getData()<< endl;
    cout << list->removeLast()->getData()<< endl;


   return 0;
}
```

SortedDoublyLinkedList.cpp

```
template<class T>
DoublyLinkedNode<T> *SortedDoublyLinkedList<T>::add(T val) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        head = new DoublyLinkedNode<T>(val);
        head->setPrevious(nullptr);
        head->setNext(nullptr);
    } else {
        DoublyLinkedNode<T> *newEl = new DoublyLinkedNode<T>(val);
        DoublyLinkedNode<T> *temp = head;
        int t = 0;
        while(temp->getData() != nullptr){
            temp = temp->getNext();
            t++;
            cout <<  t  << endl;
        }
        if(newEl->getData() > head->getData()){
            newEl->setPrevious(head);
            newEl->setNext(nullptr);
            head->setNext(newEl);
            cout <<"IF"<<endl;
        }else{
            DoublyLinkedNode<T> *temp = head;
            head = newEl;
            newEl->setPrevious(nullptr);
            newEl->setNext(temp);
            temp->setPrevious(head);


            cout << "El" << endl;
        }
    }
    numberOfElements++;
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit of the loop (which I guess is trying to print out the items)... is wrong.   The while part loops over the data while it works on elements

Your broken code :

```
    while(temp->getData() != nullptr){
        temp = temp->getNext();
        t++;
        cout <<  t  << endl;
    }
```

Somewhat more functional :

```
    while(temp != nullptr){
        cout <<  t  << ":" << temp->getData() << endl;
        temp = temp->getNext();
        ++t;
    }
```

It doesn't solve your sorting problem, but as you said above, you are going iteratively, so I leave that for you to work out.

Comment: Oh yes, now it works. Thank you! Sometimes it's hard to see those simple mistakes.